# OpenCV with Xcode 5.0

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am having a lot of trouble trying to install OpenCV for Xcode 5.0 (I want to do this in C++). Everywhere I've looked it seems like people are installing it for Xcode 4.x. Does anybody have any suggestions/tutorials on where I can find resources to install OpenCV for Xcode 5.0/5.1?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Xcode 5 and OpenCV 2.4.8.

Here is what I suggest:

1) Download and install OpenCV, build it using CMake.

2) Once installed, you can drag libopencv*.dylib files found in your /lib dir (in my case /usr/local/lib ), in to your project under "build phases"

3) Include OpenCv headers, write your code.